# Passing variable values to the eval function

Tags: java, matlab

When this piece of code is executed the program uses the matlabcontrol library to open MATLAB and execute the given lines inside the eval(). The problem is in the first line i.e. `m.eval("image1=imread('D:/My Hand Gestures/f.jpg');");` takes a fixed String value as input. But here i want to store the path in a variable and pass it to the `imread()` function. How am i supposed to do that? Any help is appreciated. Here is the code.

```
package Interface;

import matlabcontrol.MatlabConnectionException;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabInvocationException;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabProxy;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabProxyFactory;
/**
 *
 * @author Rajdeep
 */
public class Output {

    private static String check;
    private static String path;

    Output(){
        //default constructor
    }

    Output(String s,String p){
        check = s;
        path=p;
    }

    //GrayScale Conversion Function
    public static void grayScale(String p,MatlabProxy m)throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException{

    m.eval("image1=imread('D:/My Hand Gestures/f.jpg');");
    m.feval("image1","imread(path)");   
    m.eval("figure,imshow(image1);");
    m.eval("image_gray=rgb2gray(image1);");
    m.eval("figure,imshow(image_gray);");
    m.eval("final_image=imresize(image_gray,0.03125);");
    m.eval("figure,imshow(final_image);");
    m.eval("imwrite(final_image,'C:/Users/Desktop/f.jpg');");


    //Disconnect the proxy from MATLAB
    m.disconnect();
    }


    //Median Filtering Function
    public static void Filter(String p, MatlabProxy m)throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException{
    m.eval("I=imread('D:/gestures/f.jpg');");
    m.eval("J = medfilt2(I, [4 4]);");
    m.eval("figure,imshow(J);");
    m.eval("imwrite(J,'C:/Users/Rajdeep/Desktop/f.jpg');");


//Disconnect the proxy from MATLAB
    m.disconnect();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     * @throws MatlabConnectionException
     * @throws MatlabInvocationException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException
{
    //Create a proxy, which we will use to control MATLAB
    MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory();
    MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();
    Output out=new Output("GrayScale","D:/My Hand Gestures/f.jpg");

        if(check == "GrayScale") {
               grayScale(path, proxy);
        }
        if(check== "Filter"){
                Filter(path,proxy);

        }



}

}
```

Here i created a path variable that has a predefined path. I want to use this variable instead of giving the path as in the above mentioned process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this to start with. See if it helps.

`String path_variable = "D:/My Hand Gestures/f.jpg";`
`m.eval("image1=imread('" + path_variable + "');");`

Comment: Thanks, that absolutely worked. You saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: It was that simple. I never thought it this way.